# Can't edit unique values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some difficulties with editing data. I have some property - ISBN. I put it to have a unique value. When I create new data it's ok but when I try to edit, it wrights that is already in use. What can I do?

Class Books:

```
[Remote("IsISBNExists", "Book", ErrorMessage = "ISBN number is already in use")]
public string ISBN { get; set; }
```

BookController:

```
public JsonResult IsISBNExists(string Isbn) {
    return Json(!bookContext.Books.Any(x => x.ISBN == Isbn), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the ID of the record you are editing and use that to determine if the ISBN is in use..

Just add your Book ID field in the AdditionalFields parameter to include it in the validation request.

```
[Remote("IsISBNExists", "Book", AdditionalFields = "BookID", ErrorMessage = "ISBN number is already in use")]
public string ISBN { get; set; }
```

then use that field in your validation

```
public JsonResult IsISBNExists(string Isbn, int BookID) {
    return Json(!bookContext.Books.Any(x => x.BookID != BookID && x.ISBN == Isbn), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```